# Phantomjs append to file with fs.write

Tags: phantomjs

How can I append to a file using `fs.write()`?

Using fs.write on the same files overwrites the content:

```
var fs = require('fs');
try {
    fs.write("file.txt", "Hello World", 'w');
    fs.write("file.txt", "Hello World", 'w');
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use append mode `a` instead of [over]write mode `w` in the fs.write call.

```
var fs = require('fs');
try {
    fs.write("file.txt", "Hello World", 'a');
    fs.write("file.txt", "Hello World", 'a');
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I inferred this based on the <s>python [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)</s> C [`fopen`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/fopen) documentation; Glad it worked, other file modes may work but were not tested by me.

Comment: Can we out data extracted from 2 functions into 2 seperate columns in csv ?

Comment: @Srinivas08 Its possible sure, if you can get each row's next column in order, [I would suggest doing so with two generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generators), and append the values one at a time in the right order, each column for each row, it might work. However that might be a lot of overhead for a large amount of data to do that manny writes, and it would be really easy to make a malformed csv this way. If possible I'd suggest abstract your data into a two dimensional hash/dictionary and using a csv exporter.