# How to add/append my results to a text file in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, text, append, phantomjs, casperjs

For some reason I cannot fathom out how to append text to a text file already contating data I need

I have currently got the script just console.log my data.

```
casper.then(function() {
    if (this.exists('.srBtnRed')) {
        this.echo(casper.cli.get(0) + "|" + casper.cli.get(1) + " Up Impossible !!");
        this.exit();
    }
});
```

Can anybody edit the above code to save the result to the next clean line of results.txt

Also I do have `require('fs')` in my script .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phantomjs append to file with fs.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631963/phantomjs-append-to-file-with-fs-write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` prints to the console, you are likely looking for *filesystem* module.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.write('results.txt', casper.cli.get(0) + "|" + casper.cli.get(1) + " Up Impossible !!", 'a');
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857024/1132711)

[Source #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25631964/1132711)

Comment: this works in a fashion but it is not keeping the data its delting the data then adding the line can u help

Comment: Strange. the flag `'a'` in the end tells to open the file in *append mode*. Are you sure you did not accidently remove the flag? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25631964/1132711 - same solution, and is reported to be working.